# The function '$initGetIt' isn't defined while using injectable pub package

Tags: flutter, dart, package, inject

I am trying to implement stacked architecture by following this video uploaded by FilledStacks.
I encountered a problem while using injectable pub package
https://pub.dev/packages/injectable

My locator.dart class code is as follow

```
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';
import 'package:injectable/injectable.dart';

final locator = GetIt.instance;

@injectableInit
void setupLocator() => $initGetIt(locator);
```

on  `$initGetIt(locator)` I'm getting this error

```
The function '$initGetIt' isn't defined.
Try importing the library that defines '$initGetIt', correcting the name to the name of an existing function, or defining a function named
```

Even though I am implementing package the way it is shown in the package documentation

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DO8le1W_HqQ&t=914s

Comment: You have not accepted the right anwer for your question

Answer (score 21):

Add `injectable_generator` package in pubspec.yaml below `dev_dependencies:`

**Your pubspec.yaml file should look like this:**

```
dependencies:
  ...other dependencies
  get_it: ^7.2.0
  injectable: ^2.1.0 # Version 2
  json_annotation: ^4.7.0

dev_dependencies:
  ...other dependencies
  build_runner: ^2.3.3
  injectable_generator: ^2.1.3 # Version 2
  json_serializable: ^6.5.4
```

**And your code should look like this:**

**For injectable version 1:**

```
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';
import 'package:injectable/injectable.dart';

GetIt getIt = GetIt.instance;

@InjectableInit(preferRelativeImports: false)
void setup() => $initGetIt(getIt);
```

**For injectable version 2:**

```
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';
import 'package:injectable/injectable.dart';

GetIt getIt = GetIt.instance;

@InjectableInit(preferRelativeImports: false)
void setup() => getIt.init();
```

Run `flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs and fix`

Import the `injector.config.dart` file:

```
import 'package:<app_name/your_injector_file_path>/injector.config.dart';
```

Comment: The last line with the import is crucial, I wonder why it is not mentioned in the official documentation

Answer (score 11):

1. Add in pubspec.yaml in dev_dependencies: `injectable_generator:`
2. Run `flutter packages pub run build_runner build`
3. Import `$initGetIt` from generated file

Comment: I would also suggest to run "flutter pub run build_runner watch --delete-conflicting-outputs" instead of the second step. It will make sure you dont need to be re-running this second step multiple times after editing files.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `injectable` 2.1.0 or above use below:

```
@InjectableInit(asExtension: false)
FutureOr<GetIt> _init(GetIt getIt) => init(getIt);
```

then run the build_runner:

```
flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

Answer (score 0):

After succesfully run on terminal

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build
```

Import the generated file .config.dart into your file

```
import 'locator.config.dart';
```

where my file with named locator, so the generated file called locator.config.dart

Answer (score 0):

``

this is with the version of
injectable: ^2.3.2
injectable_generator: ^2.4.1

`import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';
import 'package:injectable/injectable.dart';
import 'package:movie_app/di/injection.config.dart';

GetIt getIt = GetIt.instance;

@InjectableInit(
initializerName: 'init', // default
preferRelativeImports: true, // default
asExtension: true,
)
void configureInjection(String environment) {
getIt.init();
}`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).